# How to fake service injected in a component that makes HTTP calls?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, angular8

I am new to Angular and trying to learn unit testing. I have a very simple component, that depends on a service (**UserService**). In the **ngOnInit()** life cycle hook, I am calling a method of the service and storing the data it returns in a property. In my view, I have a list bound to this property.

This is the code of my component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { UserService } from "../services/user.service";
import { User } from "./models/user";

@Component({
 selector: "app-home",
 templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
 styleUrls: ["./home.component.css"]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
 users: User[] = [];
 constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(x => {
     this.users = x;
   });
 }
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users" class="user-item">{{ user.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

User service looks like this

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { User } from "../home/models/user";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class UserService {
  private baseUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/users`);
  }
}
```

Everything works as expected. I am trying to write some unit tests for this component. I have created some fake data

```
import { User } from "../home/models/user";

export const FakeData = {
  users: <User[]>[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "User 1",
      username: "User1",
      email: "User1@fakemail.com",
      phone: "123 456 789",
      website: "afraz.com"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "User 2",
      username: "User2",
      email: "User2@fakemail.com",
      phone: "123 456 789",
      website: "afraz.com"
    }
  ]
};
```

These are the tests that I have added

```
import {
  async,
  ComponentFixture,
  TestBed,
  fakeAsync,
  flush
} from "@angular/core/testing";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";
import { UserService } from "../services/user.service";
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { FakeData } from "../fakes/fake-data";
import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser";

describe("HomeComponent", () => {
  let component: HomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;
  let userService: UserService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [HomeComponent],
      providers: [UserService]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // Mock the user service
    userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
    spyOn(userService, "getUsers").and.returnValue(of(FakeData.users));
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
    component = null;
  });

  it("should create component", () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("should get 'Users' from the service", fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.users.length).toEqual(2);
    });
  }));

  it("should bind 'Users' to the view", fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      const userList = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css(".user-item"));
      expect(userList.length).toEqual(2);
    });
  }));
});
```

Now here is where I am confused, I am getting following error in the output

*'Spec 'HomeComponent should bind 'Users' to the view' has no expectations.'*

*'Spec 'HomeComponent should get 'Users' from the service' has no expectations.'*

The problem is that if I use **Async** instead of **fakeAsync** then the actual User Service is called, and I do not want to do that. My expectation is that since I have the following line of code

`spyOn(userService, "getUsers").and.returnValue(of(FakeData.users));`

in the **beforeEach()** block, therefore the actual code should not be executed and instead this hard coded data should be returned. Can anyone please help and explain what am I missing?

**UPDATE: Here is my final working code of the tests.** Thanks for the quick help! Hopefully it will help someone else as well :)

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";

import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";
import { UserService } from "../services/user.service";
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { FakeData } from "../fakes/fake-data";
import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser";

describe("HomeComponent", () => {
  let component: HomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;
  let userServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<UserService>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    userServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj(["getUsers"]);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [HomeComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: UserService, useValue: userServiceSpy }]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    userServiceSpy.getUsers.and.returnValue(of(FakeData.users));
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
    component = null;
  });

  it("should create component", () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("should have 'Users' populated", () => {
    expect(component.users.length).toEqual(2);
  });

  it("should bind 'Users' to the view", () => {
    const userList = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css(".user-item"));
    expect(userList.length).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

Comment: I do not want to use a fake service, I am looking for a way to somehow fake the call to the actual service or create a fake in the test using Jasmine and use it to return data.

Comment: I think the problem is that component.ngOnInit(); is not called when tests are executed. If I call it manually and don't mark my test as fakeAsync or Async then the tests pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to avoid the use of `fakeAsync` altogether. I believe in your case you are calling `fixture.detectChanges()` prior to setting up your spy - which is why the 'real' service is being called.

Create your `UserService` spy in your test and register it as a provider to the `HomeComponent`:

```
describe('HomeComponent', () => {
  let comp: HomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;

  let userServiceSpy: SpyObj<UserService>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    userServiceSpy= createSpyObj(['getUsers']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [ HomeComponent ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .overrideComponent(HomeComponent , {
      set: {
        providers: [
          { provide: UserService, useValue: userServiceSpy }
        ]
      }
    })
    .compileComponents()
      .then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    userServiceSpy.getUsers.and.returnValue(of(FakeData.users));
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't compile some part of the code that you posted and I am not sure if I should be able to import them from somewhere.

createSpyObj(['getUsers']); is this a function you have defined somewhere? Also, I am not sure about schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ] and TestBed.createComponent(TransferComponent); 

Do I need NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA and TransferComponent?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I am new to Angular and did not realize that createSpyObj was a function in Jasmine. I changed it to jasmine.createSpyObj(["getUsers"]); Now the code compiles!

Comment: This code is working perfectly! Thanks a lot. Can you please elaborate one thing for me to remove my confusion? Why are the imports empty in the configureTestingModule even though the actual service depends on HttpClient? Is it because in the test we are totally using a fake service?

Comment: Yes that is right. You do not need the import, since you are not really calling the getUsers function and therefore do not need its dependencies

Comment: Sorry I was merging some of my code with your example and missed the imports. @RonaldHund is correct - for the tests to create an instance of `HomeComponent` it needs to know how to provide any dependencies. Originally you had the real `UserService` set as the provider in your testing module. `UserService` has its own dependency on `HttpClient`, hence the need to import `HttpClientModule`. The revised version says to `useValue: userServiceSpy` (so anytime something asks for the `UserService`, use the spy instead). There is no longer anything depending on `HttpClient` - so no imports required.